# Как распределить правдоподобным способом комиссии по сделкам

Tags: математика, любой-язык

Есть магазин, который в течение определенного времени совершал сделки, платя за них комиссии. К концу месяца комиссий у него набралось 1000 рублей. Но вот проблема - мы не знаем, сколько он заплатил за каждую сделку (понятия не имею, как так получилось, не суть). Зато знаем сумму каждой сделки.

Как правдоподобным способом задним числом распределить эти комиссии по сделкам, сохранив сумму комиссий?

Например, допустим, сделка на 500 рублей дает комиссию 1 рубль, сделка на 600 - комиссию 1.5 рубля и так далее. Можно же найти, из чего состоит эта 1000 рублей, применив математические законы? Спасибо.

Comment: Да, именно так. Точно же все равно не получится?

Comment: Пропорционально сумме сделки распределите.

Comment: @ArkadyTkach, неужели никто не знает, как определяется размер комиссии??

Comment: комиссия за сделку = 1000 * (сумма сделки / сумма всех сделок)